# translation in quotes words using gettext

Tags: translation, gettext

I need translate this sentence:
        My name is "Josep", whar's your name?

In the po file, this sentence would be:

```
    msgid "My name is "Josep", whar's your name?"
    msgstr "El meu nom es "josep" Quin es el teu"
```

But this throw a error when I make the .mo file due to quotes inside josep name.
How can I scape this character?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape your " as \".